# Windows Server 2022: ошибка управляемости

Tags: windows-server

Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
Активированный
В диспетчере серверов постоянная ошибка управляемости:

```
В сети: сбои при получении данных
```

В подробнее:

```
Системе не удаётся получить доступ к одному или нескольким журналам событий из-за недостаточных прав доступа, повреждения файла или по другим причинам. Дополнительные сведения см. в канале Operational журнала ошибок ServerManager-ManagmentProvider на целевом сервере.
```

Кто сталкивался, подскажите, что надо делать или хотя бы где найти этот журнал?

sfc /scannow ошибок не выявил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в некорректном удалении VirtualSVN.

Логи находятся в Просмотр событий -> Журналы приложений и служб -> Microsoft -> Windows -> ServerManager-ManagmentProvider -> Operational